# How to find $f(x)$ from given condition $f^2(x)=1+\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R }$ satisfy the following
>
> $$(f(x))^2 = 1+\int_0^x f(t) \, \mathrm d t$$
>
> How can we find $f(x)$?

I don't know how to attack such a problem. Please give me some hints on how to move on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take derivative on both side of  $2f(x)f'(x)=f(x)$ implies

$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ so what is $f(x)$

we will get $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}+c$

and $f^2(x)$=$1+\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$ implies $f(0)=\pm 1$ so you will get the value of $c$

Comment: There is one more condition because $(f(0))^2 = 1$, so $f(x) = \frac{x}{2}\pm 1$

Comment: Note that you have to assume $f(x)\neq 0$ in the derivation.

Comment: Ooh so the final answer is  $f(x)=\frac{x}{2} \pm 1$

Comment: yeah you got it.

Comment: As it stands, the proof is not entirely correct: besides the (easy) part that asks you to justify the fact that you *can* differentiate, there is the point raised by @MrYouMath: you technically, and merrily, divide by zero.

Comment: Question said nothing about the differentiation, does it mean the solution is wrong ??

Comment: @ClementC we also derivate while the wording of the problem doesn't give any indication of the regularity on $f$, what do we care about zero :-) @ OP No, solution is correct, but there can be others, more tricky ones.

Comment: @zwim: the two solutions found do satisfy the functional equation. I do not deny it; I am merely pointing out that the derivation ("[blabla" **implies** [blabla]" specifically) is wrong. And, as *you* point out, in the process it does not rule out the existence of a plethora of other solutions.

Comment: @zwim: I think that the answer should be more carefully stated. In this case, it didn't matter but for some other case, we might lose a meaningful solution to the problem. $f(x)=0$ is clearly not a solution to the problem but we should at least mention that.LOL, you sounded damn serious :D.

Comment: @MrYouMath I agree with that. (check there was a smiley)

Comment: @MrYouMath It's not only the identically zero function. Here, Master X essentially derives "$f(x) = 1/2$ *for all $x$*" from the first line, derivation which is not correct if $f$ cancels at *any* $x$.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, I see that point also in the final solution. But as it is not a problem of the final solution I would not consider that problematic. How would we go about showing that this is not problematic without checking the final solution? Btw I would rather think of the problem as $f(x)(2f'(x)-1)=0$. And then say $f(x)=0$ or $2f'(x)-1=0$. This way we do not have the trouble with $f(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: @MrYouMath To be honest, I suspect the problem is ill-posed to begin with -- the OP is likely missing some crucial assumption. For instance, that $f$ is assumed continuous (i.e., only looking for continuous solutions), otherwise the very first step (differentiation) can already be an issue.

Comment: Can i give thumbs up to Master X???

Comment: The problem implies that whenever $f(x)$ is defined, the integral $\int_0^x f(t) d t$ is defined. A reasonable assumption is then that $f$ is defined in an interval containing $0$ and that it is Lebesgue-integrable on compact subintervals. This assumption and the equation imply that $f^2$ is absolutely continuous, hence $f$ is continuous. Bootstraping the argument shows that $f^2 \in {\cal C}^1$, hence $f$ is ${\cal C}^1$ on every interval where $f(x)\not = 0$. On such intervals, it can be only $\pm 1 + x/2$, and continuity does the rest.

Comment: @Gribouillis Don't you get only [differentiability a.e.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Generalizations) (which is strictly weaker than absolute continuity)? I may be a tad rusty.

Comment: @ClementC. No I really get $C^1$ on intervals where $f\not = 0$. However, when $f=0$, it could remain zero on more than one point. For example $f(x) = 1+x/2$ for $x\ge -2$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x < -2$ seems to be a solution. Similarly, if $f(x) = -1+x/2$ for $x\le 2$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x > 2$ seems to be a solution. So I would say the problem has 4 solutions.

Comment: @Gribouillis My comment referred to the part where you say "This assumption and the equation imply that $f^2$ is absolutely continuous,"

Comment: @ClementC. If $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable on bounded intervals, then $\int_0^x f(t) d t$ is absolutely continuous.... But now it seems to me that there are more solutions ! $f(x) = -1 + x/2$ until $x=2$, then $0$ until $x=a>2$, then $(x-a)/2$.

Comment: @Gribouillis OK, so I may be mistaken. Do you have a reference for that theorem? The Wikipedia article I linked above only states differentiability a.e., *not* absolute continuity.

Comment: @ClementC. [This link](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/absolutely-continuous-functions-review) looks good. Read especially the end of the page and the page of classification of absolutely continuous functions.

Comment: @Gribouillis thanks.

Comment: There are other errors in all this, for example $f^2$ continuous does not imply that $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Let us explore the possibly non continuous solutions of the equation. We suppose that $f$ is a solution defined in an interval $I$ containing $0$, such that $f \in L^1([a, b])$ for every compact interval $[a,b]\subset I$.

Let us define $\epsilon(x) = \text{sgn}(f(x))$, so that $f(x) = \epsilon(x)g(x)$ and $g(x)$ is non negative. Substituting in the original equation, we get
$$g^2(x) = 1 + \int_0^x \epsilon(t) g(t) d t$$
As $g$ is non negative, we may write
$$g(x) = \sqrt{1 + \int_0^x \epsilon(t) g(t) d t}$$
The integral in this expression is an absolutely continuous function of $x$ and the above expression shows that $g$ is a continuous function of $x$.

We can go a little further because we know that for almost all $x$, the integral is differentiable at $x$ and
$$\left(\int_0^x \epsilon(t) g(t) d t\right)^\prime = \epsilon(x) g(x)$$ We deduce that for almost every point $x$ such that $g(x)\not = 0$, one has
$$g^\prime(x) = \frac{\epsilon(x) g(x)}{2\sqrt{1 + \int_0^x \epsilon(t) g(t) d t}} = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon(x)$$

We know that $g(0)=1$, so that $g(x)>0$ in a neighbourhood of $0$. In this neighbourhood, the above equation implies that
$$g(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{2} E(x)\quad \text{where}\quad \boxed{E(x)=\int_0^x \epsilon(t) d t}$$
We deduce that
$$\boxed{f(x) = \epsilon(x)\left(1 + \frac{1}{2} E(x)\right)}$$
From this formula, it is easy to check the original equation when $\epsilon(x)\not = 0$ because
$$\int_0^x f(t) d t = \int_0^x (\epsilon(t) + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon(t) E(t)) d t = E(x) + \frac{1}{4}E^2(x) = f^2(x) - 1$$
Obviously, any function $f$ defined by the above formula, where $\epsilon(x)$ is a measurable function with value in $\{-1, 1\}$ is solution of the initial problem (even if $\epsilon(x)$ is not the sign of $f$).

There remains the question to determine if all the solutions have this form. This is probably not the case because one can imagine intervals where $\epsilon(x) = 0$ and $E(x) + \frac{1}{4} E^2(x) = -1$ and the equation is satisfied. On such intervals, one would have $f(x) = 0$ and $E(x) = -2$.